# Ghost writing like on tumblr signup page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Does anyone know how to create a tumblr like field as they have on

http://www.tumblr.com/

It's the URL field where some faded text is there then when you click on it, and type, it appends some text ... .tumblr.com that you cannot erase or highlight or whatever.  The javascript is obfuscated so I really have no clues on how it was accomplished
I'd prefer jquery but really as long as it works...

Much regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I just looked at it again. It takes the input as you type it and adds it into the ghostwriter span that lays above the input field. Pretty simple, really. The ".tumblr.com" text is just in the span itself. Something to the effect of: `<span id="ghostwriter"><span id="ghostwriter-copy">Your Input</span>.tumblr.com</span>`

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery Plugin for that!

https://github.com/michelgotta/jquery-ghostinput-plugin

Demo: 
http://michelgotta.de/ghost-input-demo/

Comment: I'm having trouble using your plugin with a field that I have already defined that has it's own styling.  How do I use your plugin with my own field?

Comment: I just used the following styles and added a listener to the .ghostInput_input span for the click event to pass the focus on my input `.ghostinput, 
.ghostInput_input, 
.ghostInput_label {
 position:absolute;
 padding:5px 0;
 outline:0;
 margin:0;
}
.ghostinput {
 border: none;
 z-index:1000;
 background-color: transparent;
}
.ghostInput_wrapper {
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
}
.ghostInput_label {
 z-index:999;
 color:#888;
 
}
.ghostInput_input {
 left: 6px;
 color:#888;
}
.ghostInput_copy {
 visibility: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
}` _btw, sorry for the format_